# Is there a way to view the body / contents of a system function in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

For the sake of leaning and exploring, I'd like to look at how some of the system functions are built. Is there a way to do this in sql server 2008 or R2?

I've tried sp_helptext 'Sum' but I get an error saying that the resource cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `Sum` is stored as a T-SQL function in your system that you could "peek" into. That's most likely code deep inside the SQL Server core.

As a proof - you *can* e.g. get the body of other system stored functions using `sp_helptext`:

```
sp_helptext 'sys.fn_isrolemember'
```

That works just fine - so that leads me to believe that `Sum` isn't a stored function as such.

Comment: Maybe functions like sum are built using the clr integration?

Comment: @BrianDishaw: there are newer options that are indeed built using the SQL-CLR (things like the `HierarchyID` type and its operations) - but I'm pretty sure `sum` is so common that it's in the SQL Server core code base.